# ngResource return a singular item

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ngresource

When trying to return a singular item from a mongoDB I keep getting an error telling me I am returning an array as apposed to an object. Here's my service code:

```
resource: $resource('http://localhost:8080/api/item/:itemId', null, {'get' : {method: 'GET'}}, {stripTrailingSlashes: false})

function getItem(itemId) {
  return this.resource.get({itemId: itemId}).$promise.then(function(resource){
    return resource;
  });
}
```

The service is above is called resolve like so:

```
.state('cocktail', {
  templateUrl: 'client/app/features/item/item/item.html',
  controller: 'ItemController',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  data:{
    title: 'Item'
  },
  params:{
    itemId: null
  },
  resolve:{
    item: getItem
  }

function getItem($stateParams, itemService) {
    return itemService.getItem($stateParams.itemId);
}
```

Then in my controller:

```
ItemController.$inject = ['itemService', 'item'];

function ItemController(itemService, item) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.item = item;
}
```

The object that is returned in the call is:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "57586f25661d33fe21057866",
        "name": "Red Velvet",
        "description": "Red Velvet Description here",
        "image": "red-velvet",
        "__v": 0,
        "gred": []
     },{
        "_id": "57586f25661d33fe21057884",
        "name": "Red Item",
        "description": "Red Velvet Item here",
        "image": "red-velvet-item",
        "__v": 0,
        "gred": []
     },
]
```

The error I get in my console is - [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array. I am not expecting an array but the object of the ID I pass through in the resolve. If anyone has any comments or can see what I'm doing wrong please let me know! This is bugging me and I know it's going to be a simple fix haha!

Comment: This is a problem with your api, not your angular code. If the endpoint is supposed to only return one item, limit it to one item before you send it back in the response. In that particular instance what is being passed as the `itemId` to your api?

Comment: It was an issue with my $state.go from my list controller I had it like so - $state.go('item', itemId); but instead it should of read $state.go('item', {itemId: itemId});